# NextJS AI SDK not working with Azure OpenAI when connecting via langchain

Tags: azure, next.js, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain

I am using Vercel AI SDK with NextJS and trying to make it work with Azure OpenAI through langchain. Although, I am able to connect with Azure OpenAI directly (that is without langchain). I want to connect through langchain (as langchain provides so many features to handle data and chat).
Below is the route.ts file

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { Message as VercelChatMessage, StreamingTextResponse } from "ai";
import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import { BytesOutputParser } from "langchain/schema/output_parser";
import { PromptTemplate } from "langchain/prompts";

export const runtime = "edge";

const formatMessage = (message: VercelChatMessage) => {
  return `${message.role}: ${message.content}`;
};

const TEMPLATE = `You are a pirate named Patchy. All responses must be extremely verbose and in pirate dialect.
 
Current conversation:
{chat_history}
 
User: {input}
AI:`;

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const body = await req.json();
  const messages = body.messages ?? [];
  const formattedPreviousMessages = messages.slice(0, -1).map(formatMessage);
  const currentMessageContent = messages[messages.length - 1].content;

  const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(TEMPLATE);

  const model = new ChatOpenAI({
    temperature: 0.8,
    azureOpenAIApiKey: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    azureOpenAIApiInstanceName: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_INSTANCE_NAME,
    azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
    azureOpenAIApiVersion: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION,
    azureOpenAIBasePath: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_BASE_PATH,
  });

  const outputParser = new BytesOutputParser();

  const chain = prompt.pipe(model).pipe(outputParser);

  const stream = await chain.stream({
    chat_history: formattedPreviousMessages.join("\n"),
    input: currentMessageContent,
  });

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. In plain NodeJS, the below model will work.

```js
const model = new ChatOpenAI({
    temperature: 0.8,
    azureOpenAIApiKey: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    azureOpenAIApiInstanceName: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_INSTANCE_NAME,
    azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
    azureOpenAIApiVersion: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION,
    azureOpenAIBasePath: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_BASE_PATH
});
```

But in order for it to work with NextJS and Vercel AI SDK, remove `azureOpenAIBasePath`.